# How to capture soft delete as DELETE statement in SQL trigger

Tags: sql-server

I have `Action` and `ActionHistory` tables. I have an insert and update trigger which will insert the inserted/updated statement record into the `ActionHistory` table with the `OperationType` column indicating the operation type of insert/update/delete/undelete.

[image]

Since we are using `IsDelete` flag in the `Action` table for soft deletes, it will be an update statement when user deletes/undelete the record. I want to capture that record as deleted/undeleted in the `ActionHistory` through a trigger.

Comment: So what is wrong with handling a soft deletion through an update trigger, as you have already mentioned?

Comment: When user delete/undelete record, I update the IsDeleted flag through SP. That will raise the update trigger. In the update trigger I have no way to know whether that was a record update or it was for delete/undelete

Comment: Can't you compare the previous and current values of `IsDeleted` to figure this out?

Comment: Yes that can be done. Thanks. Now I am feeling silly for asking the question for obvious solution :)

Comment: No, it's a good question +1.  And also, it opens another question which is how can you distinguish between an update operation intended to be an update, versus one which is intended to be a deletion.

Comment: What RDBMS do you use? Please add corresponding tag, is it SQL Server, Mysql, PostgreSQL or any other? They all have different ways to specify triggers

Comment: Triggers are completely vendor specific, so we have to know which DBMS product you are using.

Comment: I have updated the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The same way as with an insert trigger. In an update trigger, inserted
>   contains the new values, and deleted contains the old.

```
Create Trigger [dbo].[TrackingTrigger]
ON Action
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        -- Action which would you want For Insert
        INSERT INTO ActionHistory (Id, Name, IsDeleted, OperationType)
        SELECT Id, Name, IsDeleted, "INSERT" FROM inserted
    END
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted) AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        -- Action which would you want For Update
        INSERT INTO ActionHistory (Id, Name, IsDeleted, OperationType)
        SELECT Id, Name, IsDeleted, 
            CASE WHEN deleted.IsDeleted = inserted.IsDeleted  THEN "Update" 
                 WHEN deleted.IsDeleted = 0 AND inserted.IsDeleted = 1 THEN "Delete"
                 WHEN deleted.IsDeleted = 1 AND inserted.IsDeleted = 0 THEN "UnDelete"
        FROM deleted
    END
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I will implement as per your code and will update your answer as accepted.

Comment: Yes it mostly worked, had to tweak a little. Need inner join with inserted in else block and column should be inserted.Id... and so on. I will accept this as a solution thanks